# React native video make private downloads directly

Tags: android, ios, react-native, video-encoding, react-native-fs

```
import Video from 'react-native-video';

<Video source={{uri: "background"}}   
       ref={(ref) => {
         this.player = ref
       }}                                      
       onBuffer={this.onBuffer}                
       onError={this.videoError}
       style={styles.backgroundVideo} />

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundVideo: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
});
```

Hey i am using the above code but the problem is i want to give a download button so that users can download videos. This is working fine with the help of these libraries.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch-blob

Problem: I want to make videos private like mxplayer, netflix. So that users can access videos from my app only not from galley or mobile storage folder. I will take mobile storage but in encoded format. So that they can not share that videos. just Download it access via app and can delete it. Please let me know if anybody have a good tutorial.

[Watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfObQmSWjkk)

You can watch the above video. Anybody have a idea that how mx doing this thing. I want to do same. Download videos and save and will be private and play in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to encrypt the video file then save it so that the gallery/other media player cannot access the video. By only using your app you can decrypt the video. To encrypt and decrypt video files you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-media-crypto this library.

Comment: Hi @Amit Dutta Do you have any idea how to use with a url. So that video will download the encrypt and save in the storage.

Comment: more info added in the question. Please check.

Comment: There is a hack that you could use, First download the video but change the file extension so that it will not identify as a video file and when you are reading the file just fix the extension and you get the original file.